# ResourceManager can not read strings from Resources in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use `ResourceManager` class in my `WinForm` project.

```
public class LanguageManager
    {
        private static readonly ResourceManager _rm;

        static LanguageManager()
        {
            _rm = new ResourceManager("Bein.WinForm.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
        }

        public static string GetString(string name)
        {
            return _rm.GetString(name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        public static void ChangeLanguage(string language)
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);

            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
```

I have `strings.az.resx` and `strings.ru.resx` resource files at `Form/Resources` folder. But they are referenced by `Form/Properties/Resources`

When I use `"Bein.WinForm.Properties.Resources"` as baseName for `ResourceManager`, it can not read strings from there.

When I use `"Bein.WinForm.Resources.strings"` as baseName, it can read strings and program is works. But Form Designer crushs with this error:

**"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Bein.WinForm.Resources.strings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Bein.WinForm" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed"**

Please help.